# Erro ao abrir View com valores carregados direto da classe

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

Tenho uma tela de Login padrão, onde tem a funcionalidade "Esqueci a senha", que ao ser clicado irá verificar o número do ID do usuário digitado na tela, e caso for respeitado, irá abrir uma nova View com essa mensagem:

> Nota **XPTO** = *dbo.Clientes.CliEmail*
>
> "Enviamos um e-mail para o endereço **XPTO** com instruções de
> recuperação"

Porém no método que deveria retornar esse dado para view da esse erro:

**Stack**

> InvalidOperationException: The model item passed into the
> ViewDataDictionary is of type 'System.String', but this
> ViewDataDictionary instance requires a model item of type
> 'PCI.EV.Models.Clientes'.

Seguem código.

**AccountsController**(método que consulta o e-mail de acordo com o ID):

```
 public IActionResult ForgetMyPassword(Clientes cli)
        {
            Clientes objCli = new Clientes();
           var client = objCli.ConsultarEmail(cli.CliCodigo, _config);
            if (client != null)
            {
                return View("RememberPassword", client);
            }
            return View("Login");
        }
```

na variável client é carregado o e-mail, porém ele não abre a View.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**View da mensagem**(RememberPassword)

**Obs. Tanto a view de Login, quanto a view RememberPassoword, pertencem ao mesmo controller.**

```
@model PCI.EV.Models.Clientes
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>RememberPassword</title>
    <environment include="Development">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/site.css" />
    </environment>
    <environment exclude="Development">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css"
              asp-fallback-href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
              asp-fallback-test-class="sr-only" asp-fallback-test-property="position" asp-fallback-test-value="absolute" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/site.min.css" asp-append-version="true" />
    </environment>
    <environment include="Development">
        <script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
        <script src="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
        <script src="~/js/site.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
    </environment>
    <environment exclude="Development">
        <script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-2.2.0.min.js"
                asp-fallback-src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"
                asp-fallback-test="window.jQuery"
                crossorigin="anonymous"
                integrity="sha384-K+ctZQ+LL8q6tP7I94W+qzQsfRV2a+AfHIi9k8z8l9ggpc8X+Ytst4yBo/hH+8Fk">
        </script>
        <script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/bootstrap/3.3.7/bootstrap.min.js"
                asp-fallback-src="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
                asp-fallback-test="window.jQuery && window.jQuery.fn && window.jQuery.fn.modal"
                crossorigin="anonymous"
                integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa">
        </script>
        <script src="~/js/site.min.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
    </environment>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container body-content">
        <div class="form-group">

            <br />
            <label class="control-label">Enviaremos um e-mail  com instruções para redefinição de senha.</label>
            <input type="email" asp-for="CliEmail" style="width: 150px" />
            <br />

        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Leia o erro:

> InvalidOperationException: The model item passed into the ViewDataDictionary **is of type 'System.String'**, but this ViewDataDictionary instance **requires a model item of type 'PCI.EV.Models.Clientes'**.

Na view você restringe o model ao tipo `Clientes` (**`@model PCI.EV.Models.Clientes`**) e ao chamar o método `View()` você tenta passar uma `string` como parâmetro.

Provavelmente você queira restringir o tipo da *view* para `string`.

Para isso é só mudar a primeira linha

```
@model PCI.EV.Models.Clientes
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!-- Resto do código -->
```